# Textjoin without duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to seek your help for below formula, I have a table of cells that will return either of these 3 values (Yes/No/N/A). I am trying to summarize the header of the cells that return "No" without including duplicates however its not returning all the unique headers. In the below screenshots only 600000 is returned instead of "Cost Center, Carrier (E), Service Level (DR), Consignee (M), 600000", formula in array or not makes no difference. I have been searching the internet for an answer to no avail, any help or advice is very much appreciated!

[image]
[image]

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(C3:BH3="No",IF(MATCH($C$1:$BH$1,$C$1:$BH$1,0)=(COLUMN($C$1:$BH$1)-COLUMN($B$1)),$C$1:$BH$1,""),""))
```

Comment: do you have FILTER and UNIQUE?

Comment: Hi Scott, yes I have tried Filter and Unique as alternative but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you have FILTER() and UNIQUE() then this would work

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(AJ1:AQ1,AJ3:AQ3="No"))))
```

but I had understood from your array talk that you were on 2019...

Comment: Hi SpectralInstance, I have tried the FILTER and UNIQUE approach previously but it didn't work, using the formula you advised returned the follow result "Cost Center Code, Carrier (E), Service Level (DR), Consignee (M), Cost Center Code, 600000", there is duplicate Cost Center Code.

Comment: @Kai, sorry, I've edited my formula now, you should only see one instance of 'Cost Center' (like so many aspects of Excel, UNIQUE() has a 'vertical bias')